# Define multi variables as defined struct type

Tags: python, python-3.x

I defined a struct type as here (i don't understand why use "class" instead of "strcut", if "struct" can be, let's help me) :

```
class numberstruct :
     value : int
     priority : int
     valid : bool
```

And i want define 10 variable as numberstruct struct type, like to :

```
number(10) as numberstruct
number[0].value = 1
number[0].valid = True
number[1].value = 3
number[1].valid = False
```

But i tried many way but it's can't,
please teach me how.

Comment: You want to define a list of 10 `numberstruct` instances?

Comment: This is not a struct. Variables do not have types. Python is not C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `structures` in python. You have to go with `class` . You could solve your problem by creating a `list` of `numberstruct`.

```
#declareing list
number = []  
#Adding 10 objects to list number
for i in range(0,10):
    number.append(numberstruct())
```

You could set values by :-

```
number[0].value = 10
number[0].priority = 3
number[0].valid = True
```

from `number[0]` to `number[9]`

To add a new member to list you could use

```
number.append(numberstruct())
```

To delete an element say 5 th element use

```
number.pop(5)
```

**NOTE** :- Unlike C, Python is very strict on **indentation**.So make sure that your code is perfectly intended.Other wise it won't run.

Comment: I solded my problem. Your suggest is very nearly my expected, thanks you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Not that easy unfortunately:

```
number = [numberstruct() for i in range(10)]
number[0].value = 1
number[0].valid = True
number[1].value = 3
number[1].valid = False
```

Comment: @U10-Forwad : very brief and useful

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a `struct` because Python does not have a `struct` type. There are some alternatives though.

### Named tuples

[Named tuples](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) have been around since Python 2.6. They can be used like regular tuples (hence the name), but members can also be accessed as attributes.

```
from collections import namedtuple

numberstruct = namedtuple('numberstruct', ["value", "valid", "priority"])
number = numberstruct(1, True, 0)
```

While a `namedtuple` looks a bit like a class, it's essentially a tuple. They are immutable, so you can't change values of attributes after they are created. Something like `number.value = 10` will fail.

Default values can be specified with the `defaults` parameter.

### Dataclasses

Python 3.7 adds the [`dataclasses`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) module, which simplifies the creation of classes that mainly contain values.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class numberstruct:
    value: int
    valid: bool
    priority: int

number = numberstruct(value=10, valid=True, priority=0)
```

The `@dataclass` decorator automatically adds methods such as `__init__` and `__repr__`, but otherwise they are regular classes like the one in your question. They are mutable by default and you can specify default values in the class definition.

### Creating the list

```
numbers = [
    numberstruct(1, True, 0),
    numberstruct(3, False, 0),
    ...
]
```

This works for named tuples and dataclasses. You have to pass arguments to the constructor if the fields have no default values.